# Why did Ueshiba name his art Aikido (合気道)?

Tags: aikido, history, shu-ha-ri

Morihei Ueshiba training in Daitō-ryū aiki-jūjutsu under Takeda Sōkaku, and after engaging with the Ōmoto-kyō religion, changed his teaching of Daitō-ryū to encompass more of his religion ideology. He started calling his new art "aiki budo" and then in 1942 renamed it to Aikido.

Why did Ueshiba chose Aikido over aiki-budo or any other variant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ueshiba himself justifies his choice of Aiki/Aikido ([Aikido Journal](https://aikidojournal.com/2016/02/03/memoir-of-the-master-by-morihei-ueshiba-with-commentary-by-stanley-pranin/), [Aikiweb](http://www.aikiweb.com/general/memoir.html)) as such:

> As ai (harmony) is common with ai (love), I decided to name my unique
>   budo Aikido, although the word "aiki" is an old one. The word which
>   was used by the warriors in the past is fundamentally different from
>   that of mine.

In the [Aikido Journal](https://aikidojournal.com/2016/02/03/memoir-of-the-master-by-morihei-ueshiba-with-commentary-by-stanley-pranin/) version, there is a note from Stanley Pranin that states:

> *Although Morihei did not actually choose the name “Aikido,” he
>   embraced its use after the name was selected. He would refer to his
>   art mostly as “Aiki” in conversation. […]*

However, no sources or reasoning beyond this was added making it hear say at best.

I could not verify when Ueshiba wrote this. Thus, I cannot tell whether this was a retro fit at the end of Ueshiba's life or an accurate representation of his thinking at the time.

The rest of the article from Ueshiba continues:

> Aiki is not a technique to fight with or defeat the enemy. It is the
>   way to reconcile to world and make human beings one family.
>
> The secret of Aikido is to harmonize ourselves with the movement of
>   the universe and bring ourselves into accord with the universe itself.
>   He who has gained the secret of Aikido has the universe in himself and
>   can say, "I am the universe." I am never defeated, however fast the
>   enemy may attack. It is not because my technique is faster than that
>   of the enemy. It is not a question of speed. The fight is finished
>   before it is begun.
>
> When an enemy tries to fight with me, the universe itself, he has to
>   break the harmony of the universe. Hence at the moment he has the mind
>   to fight with me, he is already defeated. There exists no measure of
>   time -- fast or slow.
>
> Aikido is non-resistance. As it is non-resistant, it is always
>   victorious.
>
> Those who have a warped mind, a mind of discord, have been defeated
>   from the beginning.
>
> Then, how can you straighten your warped mind, purify your heart, and
>   be harmonized with the activities of all things in Nature? You should
>   first make the kami's heart yours. It is a Great love, Omnipresent in
>   all quarters and in all times of the universe.
>
> There is no discord in love. There is no enemy of love. A mind of
>   discord, thinking of the existence of an enemy is no more consistent
>   with the will of the kami.
>
> Those who do not agree with this cannot be in harmony with the
>   universe. Their budo is that of destruction. It is not constructive
>   budo.
>
> Therefore to compete in techniques, winning and losing, is not true
>   budo. True budo knows no defeat. "Never defeated" means "never
>   fighting."
>
> Winning means winning over the mind of discord in yourself. It is to
>   accomplish your bestowed mission.
>
> This is not mere theory. You practice it. Then you will accept the
>   great power of oneness with Nature.
>
> Don't look at the opponent's eyes, or your mind will be drawn into his
>   eyes. Don't look at his sword, or you will be slain with his sword.
>   Don't look at him, or your spirit will be distracted. True budo is the
>   cultivation of attraction with which to draw the whole opponent to
>   you. All I have to do is keep standing this way.
>
> Even standing with my back toward the opponent is enough. When he
>   attacks, hitting, he will injure himself with his own intention to
>   hit. I am one with the universe and I am nothing else. When I stand,
>   he will be drawn to me. There is no time and space before Ueshiba of
>   Aikido -- only the universe as it is.
>
> There is no enemy for Ueshiba of Aikido. You are mistaken if you think
>   that budo means to have opponents and enemies and to be strong and
>   fell them. There are neither opponents nor enemies for true budo. True
>   budo is to be one with the universe; that is to be united with the
>   Center of the universe.
>
> A mind to serve for the peace of all human beings in the world is
>   needed in Aikido, and not the mind of one who wishes to be strong or
>   who practices only to fell an opponent.
>
> When anybody asks is my Aiki budo principles are taken from religion,
>   I say "No." My true budo principles enlighten religions and lead them
>   to completion.
>
> I am calm however and whenever I am attacked. I have no attachment to
>   life or death. I leave everything as it is to the kami. Be apart from
>   attachment to life and death and have a mind which leaves everything
>   to Him, not only when you are being attacked but also in your daily
>   lives.
>
> True budo is a work of love. It is a work of giving life to all
>   beings, and not killing or struggling with each other. Love is the
>   guardian deity of everything. Nothing can exist without it. Aikido is
>   the realization of love.
>
> I do not make a companion of men. Whom, then, do I make a companion
>   of? The kami. This world is not going well because people make
>   companions of each other, saying and doing foolish things. Good and
>   evil beings are all one united family in the world. Aikido leaves out
>   any attachment. Aikido does not call relative affairs good or evil.
>   Aikido keeps all beings in constant growth and development and serves
>   for the completion of the universe.
>
> In Aikido we control the opponent's mind before we face him. That is
>   how we draw him into ourselves. We go forward in life with this
>   attraction of our spirit, and attempt to command a whole view of the
>   world. We ceaselessly pray that fights do not occur. For this reason
>   we strictly prohibit matches in Aikido. Aikido's spirit is that of
>   loving attack and that of peaceful reconciliation. In this aim we
>   bring and unite the opponents with the will power of love. By love we
>   are able to purify others.
>
> Understand Aikido first as budo and then as the way of service to
>   construct the World Family. Aikido is not for a single country or
>   anyone in particular. Its only purpose is to perform the work of the
>   kami.
>
> True budo is the loving protection of all beings with a spirit of
>   reconciliation. Reconciliation means to allow the completion of
>   everyone's mission.
>
> The "Way" means to be one with the will of the kami and practice it.
>   If we are even slightly apart from it, it is no longer the Way.
>
> We can say that Aikido is a way to sweep away devils with the
>   sincerity of our breath instead of a sword. That is to say, to turn
>   the devil-minded world into the World of Spirit. This is the mission
>   of Aikido.
>
> The devil-mind will go down in defeat and the Spirit rise up in
>   victory. Then Aikido will bear fruit in this world.
>
> Without budo a nation goes to ruin, because budo is the life of loving
>   protection and is the source of the activities of science.
>
> Those who seek to study Aikido should open their minds, listen to the
>   sincerity of the kami through Aikido, and practice it. You should
>   understand the great ablution of Aiki, practice it and improve without
>   hinderance. Willingly begin the cultivation of your spirit.
>
> I want considerate people to listen to the voice of Aikido. It is not
>   for correcting others; it is for correcting your own mind. This is
>   Aikido. This is the mission of Aikido and should be your mission.

Answer (score 2):

Simply because he walked the path that leads from warrior to spiritual disciple. Removing **budō** removed reference to warriorship. Adding **Dō**, or Way, emphasises a spiritual discipline, in this case the Way of harmonising our individual Ki with that of the greater Existence.

This is all clearly explained in *The Spirit of Aikido*, by Kisshōmaru Ueshiba, in the chapter *The Ki of the Universe and Individual Ki*:

> He dedicated himself to establishing a martial art that would meet the
>   needs of contemporary people but would not be an anachronism...
>   Ultimately, Master Ueshiba concluded that the true spirit of budō is
>   not to be found in a competitive and combative atmosphere... it is to
>   be realized in the quest for perfection as a human being, both in mind
>   and body... the constant training of mind and body as a basic
>   discipline for human beings walking the spiritual path...